# Flask form data type error (unicode data not being unicode)

Tags: python, unicode, flask, whoosh

I'm writing a small webpage using flask and I stumbled upon weird error.

In simple form I want to pass 3 string values. When I try to pass any special characters (like "ł", "ą", etc.), flask gives me traceback of:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Aug/2015 16:16:32] "POST /add_tutorial HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pawel/PANEL/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/pawel/PANEL/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/contrib/fixers.py", line 148, in __call__
return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/pawel/PANEL/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/home/pawel/PANEL/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/pawel/PANEL/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/pawel/PANEL/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/pawel/PANEL/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/pawel/PANEL/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/pawel/PANEL/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/pawel/repos/tiktalik-www-panel/panel.py", line 123, in add_tutorial
author=data['author']
  File "/home/pawel/PANEL/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/whoosh/writing.py", line 784, in add_document
perdocwriter.add_column_value(fieldname, column, cv)
  File "/home/pawel/PANEL/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/whoosh/codec/base.py", line 821, in add_column_value
self._get_column(fieldname).add(self._docnum, value)
  File "/home/pawel/PANEL/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/whoosh/columns.py", line 251, in add
self._dbfile.write(v)
  File "/home/pawel/PANEL/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/whoosh/filedb/structfile.py", line 99, in write
return self.file.write(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pawel/PANEL/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/whoosh/filedb/compound.py", line 325, in write
bio.write(inbytes)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0142' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The code which crashes is:

```
def add_tutorial():
if request.method == 'POST':
    ix = indexing(INDEXDIR,BaseSchema,'tutorials')
    with ix.writer(optimize = True) as writer:
        data = {}
        data['title'] = request.form['title']  #here it crashes
        app.logger.debug(type(request.form['title']))
        data['author'] = request.form['author']
        data['difficulty'] = int(request.form['difficulty'])
        data['fileOfArt'] = request.files['file']
        data['pictures'] = request.files.getlist("pictures")
        data['lang'] = request.form['lang']
        data['tags'] = parse_tags(request.form['tags'])
        if data['title']  and data['fileOfArt']:
            subdir = plToAng(data['title'])
            subdir = subdir.replace(" ","_")
            content = data['fileOfArt'].read()
            for picture in data['pictures']:
                handle_file(picture,subdir)
            content = repl_pictures(content,data['pictures'],subdir)
            writer.add_document(
                    title=data["title"],
                    sort_title=data["title"].lower(),
                    content=content,
                    date=datetime.now(),
                    url=subdir,
                    difficulty=data['difficulty'],
                    lang=data['lang'],
                    tags=data['tags'],
                    author=data['author']
            )       
        ix.close()  
        return redirect(url_for('add_tutorial', title=data['title'],\
            difficulty=data['difficulty']))
```

When I try to force request.form['title'] encoding to "UTF-8" I get error that "TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported" (logical, as data passed is in Unicode).

Is there any way of resolving this issue? (I cannot abandon special characters)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an issue with Flask, but with Whoosh. Please post the *full traceback*.

Comment: I've edited the post with full traceback instead of error only

Comment: what's the type of all `data` members?

Comment: I think you got encoding and decoding mixed up. Your data is unicode which can be _encoded_ as UTF8 so one can't get a _decoding error_ from that encoding operation. And the traceback indicates that `whoosh` got a unicode string and tries to encode as ASCII which fails if there are characters outside the ASCII charset in that unicode string.

Comment: @bigOTHER - form has forced UTF8.

Comment: @MichałChybowski What does this mean?  `form` contains unicode objects.  Not UTF8 encoded byte strings.

Comment: For example: data['author'] = request.form['author'].encode('utf-8')

Comment: @Maarten I would do the encoding only right before it is actually needed. Text should be kept as unicode objects as long as possible to avoid multiple de- end encodings of the same data.

Comment: @MichałChybowski BTW why do you have that `data` dictionary? It is never actually used.

Comment: @BlackJack you are right. I agree that the traceback indicates woosh. I am not familliar with woosh. Maybe there is a configuration option for which encoding to use?

Comment: @Maarten Textual fields should be unicode objects and are encoded as UTF8 by default, so there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @MichałChybowski I think it's time for a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should encode strings having special characters as `utf-8` byte strings:

```
mynewstring = mystring.encode('utf-8')
```

Result will be like this:

```
>>> a = u"عاصم"
>>> a.encode('utf-8')
'\xd8\xb9\xd8\xa7\xd8\xb5\xd9\x85'
```

Comment: unfortunately, this method was not working for me (I was getting "Unable to decode unicode" error)

Comment: you will get this error if you use `decode` but I am suggesting `encode`.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I managed to fix this by adding this code to the beginning of .py file:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

Comment: That's an ugly hack. You have to `reload()` the module because the Python developers explicitly made the `setdefaultencoding()` unavailable so no one actually uses it outside the `site` module. You really should learn about unicode and encodings and handle this properly within your program.